# Telegram bot does not get updates from webhook

Tags: python, server, webhooks, telegram-bot

I have faced the following problem after moving my bot to the new server. I use webhook to get updates but now the bot does not get them from telegram servers. I tried to send POST request with curl from the remove server and bot handled it in a normal way. I checked webhook with getWebhookInfo and it returned an object with non-empty url and pending_update_count equal to 74 without errors. I guess, it means that telegram servers are not able to send POST request to my host for some reason.

OS of my server is Arch Linux.

I use pyTelegramBotAP.

```
CONFIG = ConfigParser()
CONFIG.read(os.path.join('data', 'config.ini'))

# webhook url
URL_BASE = "https://{}:{}".format(CONFIG['server']['ip'], CONFIG.getint('server', 'port'))
URL_PATH = "/{}/".format(CONFIG['telegram bot']['token'])

BOT = telebot.TeleBot(CONFIG['telegram bot']['token'])

# server that will listen for new messages
APP = web.Application()

URL = URL_BASE + URL_PATH

BOT.set_webhook(url=URL, certificate=open(CONFIG['ssl']['certificate'], 'rb'))

# Build ssl context
CONTEXT = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
CONTEXT.load_cert_chain(CONFIG['ssl']['certificate'], CONFIG['ssl']['private key'])

# Start aiohttp server
web.run_app(
    APP,
    host=CONFIG['server']['listen'],
    port=CONFIG['server']['port'],
    ssl_context=CONTEXT,
)
```

Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

Telegram webhook only talks to https endpoints, so I suggest to check your server against https connections.

Also, getWebhookInfo call returns a status object with the latest error infomation of your endpoint. Have a look of that error info and might find the exact problem.

Comment: getWebhookInfo does not return any error: {'url': 'https://MY_IP:MY_PORT/MY_BOT_TOKEN/', 'has_custom_certificate': True, 'pending_update_count': 55, 'last_error_date': None, 'last_error_message': None, 'max_connections': 40, 'allowed_updates': None}

Comment: you can check this with ngrok.io

Comment: I tried ngrok.io but received SSL error. I'm not sure if I'm using it right. When I create public key I put a domain name that ngrok gave me as Common Name and set webhook with url from ngrok + /token/

Comment: no error info in getWebHookinfo means telegram server fails to reach your server. It seems like something wrong with your server https settings.

Comment: try using letsencrypt free ssl certificate

Comment: and configure Nginx with Let'sEncript cert to handle request on the `/token/` endpoint with proxy path to port of bot application.

Comment: **note:** if you using ngrok.io you don't need use the cert in your bot. ngrok will get all requests with `https` and redirect  to app port.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Firewall on your server, It is quite possible firewall on your server is not passing message to your application.

Answer (score 0):

To check firewall status run `$ ufw status`
Please show you URL_BASE without real IP.

What operating system is on your server?
You send test request from the CURL to URL of the Telegram or of your server?

Can you getting response from your server if you run simple app?

Example:

```
from aiohttp import web

async def hello(request):
    return web.Response(text='Hello world!')

app = web.Application()
app.add_routes([web.get('/', hello)])
web.run_app(app, host='localhost', port=3003)
```

Check response:

```
$ curl localhost:3003
Hello world!
```

Please provide more detailed information on how you troubleshoot.

Comment: The OS of my server is Arch Linux. I don't use ufw, and iptables are accepting all packets. I tried to run a simple server as you described and it worked fine. I captured packets with wireshark and there are a lot of  tcp packets from telegram servers with reset flag. I sent CURL requests from my remote server.